# Python Requests Invalid URL Label error

Tags: python, shopify

I'm trying to access Shopify's API which uses a URL format of - 
`https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.xml`

e.g.`http://7ea7a2ff231f9f7:95c5e8091839609c864@iliketurtles.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml`

doing `$curl api_url` downloads the correct XML however when I do

```
 import requests
 api_url = 'http://7ea7a2ff231f9f7d:95c5e8091839609c864@iliketurtles.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml'
 r = requests.get(api_url) # Invalid url label error
```

Any idea why I'm getting this? Curl / opening the link directly in the browser is working fine. Is it because the length of the URL is too long?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that your real API key and password?? I've removed half just in case

Comment: No. Thats a dummy URL. However, the length of all the parts of the api_url is same as the original one.

Comment: oh good news! just thought I'd check! Now i'll investigate your error :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error (`'URL has an invalid label.'`) is probably a bug in `requests` library: it applies `idna` encoding (for internationalized domain names) on hostname with userinfo attached, [source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/e7786ec14fdf20e8c373eddc9ac0f67d211cb1b9/requests/models.py#L295):

```
netloc = netloc.encode('idna').decode('utf-8')
```

that might raise 'label empty or too long' error for the long username:password. You can try to [report it on the requests' issue tracker](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/new).

[`a:b@example.com` form is deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) otherwise
`requests.get('https://a:b@example.com')` should be equivalent to `requests.get('https://example.com', auth=('a', 'b'))` if all characters in username:password are from `[-A-Za-z0-9._~!$&'()*+,;=]` set.

`curl` and `requests` also differ then there are percent-encoded characters in userinfo e.g., `https://a:%C3%80@example.com` leads to `curl` generating the following http header:

```
Authorization: Basic YTrDgA==
```

but `requests` produces:

```
Authorization: Basic YTolQzMlODA=
```

i.e.:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode('YTrDgA==')
'a:\xc3\x80'
>>> print _
a:À
>>> base64.b64decode('YTolQzMlODA=')
'a:%C3%80'
```

Comment: It can also be a simple thing like using a wrong string in the request, eg. value instead of key (or vice versa) by accident.
`for file in files:  
    response = requests.get("{}/{}".format(url, file))  # you might need files[file] here`

Answer (score 3):

It's not the length of the URL. If I do:

```
import requests
test_url = 'http://www.google.com/?somereallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongurl=true'
r = requests.get(test_url)
```

returns `<Response [200]>`

Have you tried making the request with the requests Authentication parameters [detailed here](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

```
>>> requests.get('http://iliketurtles.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml', auth=('ea7a2ff231f9f7', '95c5e8091839609c864'))
<Response [403]>
```

Comment: I'm sure this is what is causing the error! Thanks a lot! One doubt though - how come curl is working fine?